# Query data and pass as input for another function in a loop Java

Tags: java, oracle, oim

I am writing an application that required to query data from oracle database and send each queried data as input to another function in java. I am not sure how to pass those queried data as input to another function. I am trying to use Arraylist but still could not able to pass as input. Any help will be appreciated. Hope to hear from you all.

```
    String dbuserName = "";
    String dbpassword = "";
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    Connection conn = null;
    Session session = null;

    try{
        // Some Connection code to database here before  below code 
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery( "SELECT ..." );
        ArrayList <String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        /*Queried data has only one column, that is useid, now need to
        send each id as input to below try/catch statement*/                
        try {
                userManager.enable(USER_LOGIN, true);
                System.out.print("\n Enabled user Successfully");                                               
        } catch (ValidationFailedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.severe("ValidationFailedException: " + e ");
        }
```

Comment: Share your existing code snippet please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you

```
while (rs.next()) {              
        int i = 1;
        result.add(rs.getString(i++));
}
```

Then in the for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<result.size()-1;i++)
{
     String USER_LOGIN=result.get(i);
    userManager.enable(USER_LOGIN, true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works for me. Now i need to make it run automatically every midnight 12AM. For this cronjob what are the different approach to do?

Comment: Rmaro,you would need to create a schedule job by writing custom scheduler in oim.